# Tab spacing in VIM

Tags: vim

I want to change tab key spacing to 4 spaces in VIM editor on CVS server.

I know the `:set tabstop=4` command is used for that but it does not have a permanent effect. After restarting VIM it changes to 8 spaces by default.  I want to change it permanently.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you just need to add it to your `.vimrc` file.

```
set tabstop=2
```

Comment: where '.vimrc' file is located?

Comment: ~/.vimrc in your home directory

Comment: You can use `vim -u path_to_vimrc` too if you want to have it elsewhere. By default, vim reads the file from your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

Extend the answer:

1. If you want to set it global, add `set ts=2` to your `~/.vimrc` - if it doesn't exist, just create new one.
2. If you want to set tabstop for a specific file, use magic mode line in vim. Let's take C++ file as an example, add the line below in the beginning or the end of file: `// vim: set ts=2`

Read more about [modeline in vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic).